# require pdo connection to database 2 questions

Tags: mysql, security, pdo

I have 2 questions, one is about security.

So i have problem to calling database connection.
I have to use database connection for menu to check session and change menu if user logged in.
The problem is that if i want to make profile page then i need recall database connection. so i call database connection 2 times.
scheme:

```
profile.php -> require("databaseconnection.php");
menu.php -> require("databaseconnection.php");
```

my guess is that, should i make 2nd db connection or i can call it at head.php what i include every page.
Example:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
$db2 = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
```

or is it safe to call it with head.php what i have included to every page?

Comment: will you connect to two different databases?

Comment: and what is the second question?

Comment: no same, and reading from same table.

Comment: why would you use two connections and not one included in each page where you need?

Comment: because i have to call to menu it always and if i try to make profile page i need recall or something because otherwish it dosent make search to database.

Comment: check Your Common Sense answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it at head.php what you include every page.

There is no point in creating 2 connections, unless you want to increase the server load.

Comment: gona test and answer for your suggest.